# What is wrong with my jboss-deployment-structure.xml? I'm trying to exclude a dependancy. The exclusion works in WAR but not in EAR

Tags: java, jboss

So we have found that JBoss 7.1 EAP provides its own version of Jackson-Databind.  This version interferes with our deployment as we have a newer version in the WAR.  We've proven out this theory by including this jboss-deployment-structure.xml at the WAR level's WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This lets the WAR deploy on its own without errors when it previously received the errors.
However, when trying to implement the same solution at the EAR level of deployment I've been unsuccessful.  I've tried putting the jboss-deployment-structure.xml in the META-INF, WEB-INF, and root level of the EAR.  I've done that with all number of different configurations but I can't get it to correctly exclude jaxrs. It's worth mentioning that this is my first run on JBoss configurations and I could be missing something incredibly simple.

EAR level file:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="myWar.war">
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out that this was the answer.  Just as it stands here.  Another developer put the same file into his build and it worked.  I don't know what the difference was between his environment and mine but I'm marking this question resolved.